# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0 in my windows i use 6.8.2 for gradle

Tags: java, gradle

i have problem with deprecated error when build using gradle, in my Windows i use gradle 6.8.2 but when i build gradle using intellij i got error like this :

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
5 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 2 up-to-date
14:09:15: Task execution finished 'build'.

but when build it it is success

how to fix my problem ?
this is depedencies what i use

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0'
    compile('org.woodylab.boot:spring-boot-starter-pebble:0.2.3')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    compile 'org.passay:passay:1.5.0'
}
```

Thanks all

Comment: It is not an error it is a warning. Your build is using features that are deprecated and likely to be removed in Gradle 7 (or changed). It has **nothing** to do with your dependencies.

Comment: so my war still can use right ? or i must change the features ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use the artifact created by the build, the build succeeds so what would be wrong with it. As stated it is a warning that your build **might** break when upgrading to Gradle 7. This has no impact on your current build or the usability of the created artifact.